# Why is my RecyclerView not below my AppBarLayout in my CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android

I'm using the new CoorindatorLayout, and the AppBarLayout is appearing over (layering over) the RecyclerView instead of having the RecyclerView anchored to the bottom of the AppBarLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Your AppBarLayout must be the first child of the CoordinatorLayout for this to work!